# IPhoto without using the "photo library"?

Tags: mac, sync, archiving, iphoto, pictures

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to use iPhoto without having all the photos and movies lumped into one giant archive file but rather store them as individual files in subfolders (similar to the way that itunes stores music).

I've been trying to sync my Wife's Mac with my desktop via the network but I can't set up any process to tell me what files have changed if they are all lumped into one giant (63gig) file

also the idea of corruption doesn't help me sleep any better if anything were to happen to that singular file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this [Macworld article](http://www.macworld.com/article/1143828/referenced_library.html) that explains the process of creating a "reference library".  I'm actually going to re-download iPhoto and give it another go.

I too hate the idea of being locked into proprietary formats or "databases" that can become get corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

The iPhoto Library file is actually a folder containing all the images in it. There is a Masters folder in it; with yearly dated folders in that with all the original picture files. If any of the database files running iPhoto did get corrupted, it would not ruin all of your images within it.

You can prove this yourself by right clicking on the iPhoto Library icon and choosing "Show Package Contents"

Comment: very interesting. Is there a way to have the os not treat the "package" as a special folder and just show me the contents with out having to prompt it?